# How to group products by any column

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'd like to use a function like this in woocommerce:

```
wc_get_products
```

How can I group products by any column of the products table? (like in SQL GROUP BY...), and order them from the newest?

Comment: by using woo query (in some cases is better) https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query or using wp query - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/

Comment: Thanks. But this is really poor of WooCommerce/WordPress documentation, as one needs to view the source code of the WP itself to get knowledge of the group by possibility...